# Number of confidence intervals for Binomial Distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, sample-size

Consider the random variable $X$ to denote the event that the confidence interval cover the unknown parameter or not. Thus, X will follow the Bernoulli distribution with a parameter $θ$, i.e. $X~Be(θ)$, where $θ=0.9$. Given that we collect $n$ random variable $X_1,X_2,…,X_n$. What is the smallest number of confidence intervals, $n$, we have to observe to guarantee that

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $\sum X_i$ has a Binomial$(n,\theta)$ distribution.

Comment: @whuber Does that mean I have to calculate a sample size for the proportion?

Comment: It means your condition on the probability translates to an inequality for $n$ which you need to solve.